# If $2^x\bmod x = 2$, how does that prove that $x$, a prime number, is prime?

Tags: prime-numbers

I saw this on l. 13 of this code [here](https://github.com/ethereum/py_pairing/blob/master/py_ecc/bn128/bn128_field_elements.py).

I don't have a degree in maths but have read about Fermat's Theorem (which a comment below prompted me to remember), and have done first year university calculus and algebra, plus self-study of maths related to cryptography.

Comment: it does not generally prove it, but what is true is that if $p$ is prime then indeed $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$ (Fermat's little theorem). The converse does not always hold, but the idea is the basis of some more sophisticated primality tests.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about Fermat's little theorem, thanks!

Comment: A counterexample for the converse would be any Carmichael number (for example $561$ is not prime but $2^{561} \equiv 2 \pmod {561})$.

Comment: [Fermat psudoprimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime) base $2$...

Comment: Right, Carmichael numbers was overkill...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already know that $x$ is a prime number, then $2^x \equiv 2 \bmod x$ merely confirms it. But if you don't know that it is or it isn't, satisfying the congruence is a pretty decent indicator.

Among the first thousand positive integers, 170 integers that are odd satisfy the congruence, but there are only 167 primes that are odd between 1 and 1000. Which means that three odd composite numbers were falsely flagged prime by our test: 341, 561, 645.

That's a failure rate of less than 1%. And if you put those three "false primes" into Sloane's OEIS, the first result will be

> A001567       Fermat pseudoprimes to base 2, also called Sarrus numbers or Poulet numbers.
>   (Formerly M5441 N2365)

http://oeis.org/A001567

Also note that the fortieth number listed there is 29341, and $\pi(29341) = 3188$. <strike>So the failure rate has gone up almost to 11%.</strike> Depending on your application, that might be perfectly acceptable.

EDIT, January 9: I got a little confused with directions of percentages yesterday. Sorry about that.

Comment: OK so there is a small probability that it may not actually be prime. I had to remind myself what the Pi function was. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function. "So the failure rate has gone up almost to 11%." $40/3188 = 0.0125$. Perhaps you mean almost by 11%. $3/170 = 0.0176$. But it has actually gone down.

Comment: Good point, thanks, I have edited accordingly.